# How can I actively cast close votes in and out of review queues simultaneously?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, vote-to-close, triage

This concerns has kept bugging me for a while, but it became even more apparent with the introduction of the Triage review queue. The long story short, I cannot reasonably help with the review queues while also actively answering, commenting on and helping with questions in my technical area.

As of today, we have 50 close votes available per day. This is usually enough when you do one or the other, although even then there have been complaints on meta exchange in the past.

Let us go through the review queues:

- Close vote

We can review 40 questions, as the number is nearly always over 1000, usually relatively easily since most of them are really poor. I would say at least 25-30, but not infrequent that I can reuse 35 close votes in there.

- First Posts

There is some to be reused in here, too. I would say about 5 in general at least out of the daily limit, 20, as this is usually under 1000 items for the time.

- Very Low Quality

This is now getting better admittedly, due to the introduction of Triage review queue, but I used to use about 1-5 votes here daily out of the daily quota, 20, as this is usually under 1000 items for the time.

- Triage

This queue seems to contain lots of really poor questions that I would like to cast close votes on. I would say at least 10 out of the daily quota, 20, as this is usually under 1000 items for the time.

As you can see, it is not unreasonable that I already use my quota up at this point for the day. Now, let us assume that I want to contribute in the tag where I have some experience. I do not know much about other tags, but my areas like C, C++, Qt and so on, they are full of really poor questions. When I am active, it is not unbelievable to cast at least 10-20 close votes if not more. How can I do this if I reuse my close votes in the queues?

I have not yet mentioned at this point that if I was going to the chat (for instance the close event chat room), I could not help others with casting close votes.

How to address this?

- Idea A

I stop contributing in one area or more.

- Idea B

Set limit X for daily close votes and do not count the close votes cast in the review queue towards that. It is possible that in this case we would need to decrease the daily quote to 20-30 or even leave it at 50.

I do not have a strong opinion about it, but this would allow one to both contribute with the technical knowledge in the desired tags as well as doing reviews.

After all, you can go to these review queues today even if you do not have close votes left. What am I supposed to do in that case if I see a really poor post? I should stop helping due to this limitation? Or what should I do when I drain my quota in the queues and I see really poor questions in my tag, which sometimes happens to be low-traffic and I cannot stop the poor answers coming in for poor questions?

It is possible that one will use workarounds instead like "Should be improved" in the triage queue for an unsalvageable question, but this is compromising the ideal workflow. I believe I either should be able to do the work properly in there or the system should disable me from reviewing. Currently, it seems to be in some in-between limbo state.

It is also possible what [rene wrote yesterday in the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20432114#20432114)

> Or maybe we are just old and grumpy humans that only want to destroy nice things...

Is there anything that I can do without reducing my contribution?

Comment: I've never considered it to be much of a problem for myself because I, unlike you, only handle the close vote queue. But now that I also handle the  triage queue I've been greeted with the dreaded *You have no more close votes* as well. Based on past communications I believe the team is strongly against increasing the daily limtis (both on close votes and reviews). Until fixed our only option is to become less grumpy... GRRRRRR!

Comment: @rene: I agree with moderators and SE team about not increasing the daily limit. I would actually even decrease it and separate the normal close votes from review queue close votes as they are different contribution types. My idea B was to have something like 10-30 close votes per day and then if you go to the review queues, you can do whatever action you like without having an impact on your "normal" close votes. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Sompuperoo: I think 100 is a bit excessive.

Comment: Related: [We need more close votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285438)

Comment: see also: [Give extra close votes, only accessible via /review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254274/165773) at MSE