# Is it appropriate to use flags when you run out of close votes

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, moderators

This is related to [We need more close votes!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes) question but as the limit has not increased I want to know if it's appropriate to start using flags to close a question when you run out of close votes? The problem here is that when you run out of close votes the only option left is to raise a mod flag, is this appropriate use of the flag? Am I wasting a moderator's time?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks this is a duplicate, I did search but couldn't find one

Comment: They're not exactly the same question - that one asks if it's OK to use mod flags when close votes expire, this one asks if it's OK to use mod flags when you've used up your daily limit. The answer is the same though: do not use mod flags simply to escalate your regular close votes. You are given a daily limit for a reason.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for the clarification, I don't bother mods (as they're busy enough) with trivial flags but wanted to know what the official stance is, I understand the limit is there for a reason so I tend to just accept I've used up my limit