# Should I avoid hitting the question/answers vote cap?

Tags: discussion, voting

I hit my daily voting cap on questions and answers on SO quite often. It's pretty easy to hit the 40 vote limit at this point, especially from browsing review queues. I'm not here to say that's unfair or request more votes. My question is about whether or not this is actually desired behaviour.

There is a badge for hitting 40 votes in a day, as well as other badges for amassing X number of votes. Those point towards incentivising votes as having a lot of (honest) voting is good for growing the site.

However the fact that a limit exists is obviously a measure to restrict how much voting an individual user does. I assume one key reason is to prevent rep farming or other abuses. But 40 votes seems a bit low for that to be the only goal. It's easy to hit 40 votes and I'm by no means a power user. With 3 review queues allowing me 20 reviews a day each, I can easily blow through the majority of my votes even without spending them on questions I'm actually interested in/answering.

So is there another reason to limit voting that I'm brushing up against and should maybe hold back on? Is the idea that perhaps I'm too loose with votes compared to what the system expects? Or am I worrying over a system that's just for catching abuse?

Comment: You've only cast 1000 votes. So you haven't been doing this for very long. My guess is that you'll probably burn out after a while.

Comment: I think its safe to assume that if they really only wanted people casting 30 votes a day instead of 40 then that's where the cap would be.

Comment: Caps are there to be reached. Consider it a challenge!

Comment: The only way people gain reputation is because other people vote for them in some way or another (vote that their edit is helpful, vote that the question is useful, vote that the answer is useful).  You've got X amount of votes to give; spend them wisely, and if you run out of votes on a given day, rest assured that a new supply will arrive tomorrow.  (I seldom reach the limit, but I seldom give zero votes in a day either.)

Answer (score 55):

No, there is no need to avoid hitting the vote cap. You utilizing your cap is a rarity. From an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285486/189134) by Shog:

> That said, very few people hit the cap regularly - in the past 90 days, only 160 voters have hit the cap even once, and only one person on Stack Overflow has used 100% of their close votes every. single. day.

The cap exists to prevent a small minority of users from completely taking over moderation duties. By having the cap, it forces users to find another area of the site to participate in, instead of continuing to close (or refuse to close) posts.

Continuing from the linked answer:

> I calculated what we'd have to gain from varying the cap based on accuracy; giving you up to twice the current daily limit of votes if you were 100% accurate with your close-voting. Using fairly moderate criteria for accuracy, and assuming everyone who hit the cap during that time would've still hit the cap if it had been higher, we'd have seen a bit more than 11 thousand more close votes during that time period (a good chunk of those from bluet).

While a higher cap would increase the number of votes, it is highly likely that only a small group would take advantage of this higher cap.

---

Keep doing what you are doing. Your votes help. The cap is there, however, to remind you that there are other things that can be done. Go perform some edits, go walk your pet, answer some questions, hike, read a book or play a game.

Comment: Since he's talking about question or answer up/down votes, as sub 3k users don't get close/open votes, this answer is slightly off topic as well. Don't think it's such a rarity with up/down votes to use them daily.

Comment: ppl r so selfish. if you read a question or answer that help you, even a bit, why not upvote for free?? i hit the cap pretty often.

Comment: @Shimmy because i'd prefer to use my limited number of votes to downvote instead. though, i guess that's really just an excuse since i almost never hit my vote cap.

Comment: Who is the hero?

Answer (score 8):

As Andy says, hitting the cap is rare. Andy mentioned the close votes limit, but just look at [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges): *Vox Populi* is one of the rarest bronze badges, rarer than many silver badges.

Hitting the 40 votes limit [requires discipline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254598/248268) and it's encouraged because StackExchange wants more votes on questions. Consider it a failure when you hit the limit without casting 40 votes; it means you voted too many answers. Good luck with your [next Electorate badge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4374739/superbiasedman?tab=badges), too!

That said, maybe sometimes you could take a pause in the voting and also answer a question or two. I see you already edit the questions, which is good; editing and answering is even better, for a change. For answers to older questions I also [proposed a new gold badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268) because there is a great need of it.

Comment: [Synonymizer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1224/synonymizer) is much rarer than [Vox Populi](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi). [Altruist](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist) and [Disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) have also been awarded fewer times, but aren't nearly as rare as the Synonymizer one.

Comment: Right, sorry; I'll correct. These require privileges though, except Disciplined which only requires some upvotes. :)

Answer (score 6):

The only time to worry about just about any cap is if it's so ridiculously high that almost no one ever hits it at all, and you're hitting it routinely. For example, [50 questions every 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit), rolling.

Mod caps, in particular — vote caps, review caps, and so forth — are a) made to be banged up against routinely in the interest of getting the job done and b) put there so no one person will dominate moderation on a site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spend more votes on questions you're genuinely interested in, I suggest you avoid casting too many votes in review queues. Personally, I avoid downvoting and flagging low-quality content at the same time. If you flag 10 really bad questions instead of downvoting them, that will save you 10 votes for other things, and bad questions will probably get closed/deleted anyway, so any votes you cast on them are kind of wasted.