# When did Stack Overflow get an extra ten close votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This isn't a bug (*far from it*), but I was delighted to see that we now have 60 close votes to deal with closure.

When did this happen?  All the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) says is, "You now have 60."  That makes it seem like it's been the case, [when it hasn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87291/175248) always been.

Comment: Not a bug, it's a test for 30 days to see what will happen.  At the end of the 30 days, we'll decide what to do next.

Comment: @bluefeet:  Ah.  I was actually looking around for that post.  Thanks for jogging my memory on it.

Comment: @Makoto http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319131/3933332

Comment: If you're going to test this, why use a tiny value of +10? Go big or go home! +100

Comment: @Pillar Considering very few users take advantage of all 60 close votes, I'm not sure why we'd consider raising it to 100.  The 60 close votes is inline  with the total number of reviews you also get.

Comment: Very few users take advantage of all 50 votes. Why even keep it at 50? Just reduce it to < 50. Unless there's a technical barrier, I don't see low-end user behavior as a reason to have an upper bound on the number votes.

Comment: @Pillar:  I've burned through 50 of 'em at a time.  Having more is always better.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I just don't accept @bluefeet's argument here against increasing it to more than 60.

Comment: @Pillar:  That was when I was actually hunting for stuff that needed to be closed.  I don't do that very often so having the extra deletes are nice, but not a common use case for everyone.

Comment: @Pillar There have been plenty of [requests for more close votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes), feel free to chime in on that request with your reasoning for it.  The current change is a **test** to see the impact on review. Don't get so greedy asking for 100. :P

Comment: @bluefeet Negotiation tactic: ask for a lot, receive what you want.

Comment: @Pillar oh, we've asked for this a lot, and often, and begged and whined ... can you please hurry up a bit so you can help out. You're only 2800 reputation short ...

Comment: @rene Trying to use my flags :)

Comment: @bluefeet OK, if 100 is too much, can we get 80 :)

Comment: _<changes code to give @DalijaPrasnikar 10 votes as punishment for asking for more>_

Comment: @bluefeet Where are they, where?????