# Don't use up flags for review tasks

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Starting off, this is me stating my opinion. I'm not saying it has to be this way, SO is a grown platform adjusted by experience and I'm a new member probably not getting some things yet.

To the point:
Yesterday and the day before I'd used up all my available flags which at the time were around 13 and 14. I also received access to LA and FP Queues afterwards so I jumped into that when I realized marking a post as unsalvageable is the equivalent of flagging it and goes into the same limits. As I'd used up all of those flags for both days, even if I wanted to help root out a helpless question I couldn't because I'd used up my flags for the day (Mainly on NAA Flags though some others were there too), leaving me no choice but to skip the task.

So what I'm thinking would be a good idea (I'm probably wrong, educate me in the comments or answers) would be to not make the Unsalvageable button count in total flags left. Thinking that the flag limit is only in place to stop new users from spam-tagging this wouldn't affect spam that much either because of the 20 Reviews/Day limit.

Again, I'm a fairly new user, my knowledge doesn't go further than FAQ posts and common sense either. I just wanted to bring this up to get a response by users that on the other hand have an idea. Thanks for reading this, I'm looking forward to Feedback.

Comment: Starting at 13 flags/day, if you use all of your flags each day and all of them are marked helpful in the day you raise them, you can reach the maximum number of flags per day, 100, in 19 days. Obviously, it will probably be a bit longer than this, as there are real-world inefficiencies.

Comment: Closely related: [We need more close votes!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes/285473#285473) (higher-rep users cast votes in review, they don't raise flags)