# New User Experience: Deep Dive into our Research on the Staging Ground – How do you feel about review badges & opt-in settings for the Staging Ground?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users, research, staging-ground

Last week, we posted here on Meta about the [new feature that we are launching, called the Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416428/16680213) – a place where newly registered, low-rep users would receive help from higher-rep Stack Overflow users to improve their questions before their questions become public on Stack Overflow. Our vision is for the Staging Ground to be where new users can get guidance in a learning environment from volunteer experienced users to improve question quality.

Our research included a diverse group of Stack Overflow users. We do not know if our analysis will hold across the network or within our other tech sites (these are all questions that are outside of the scope of this initial work).

[Past user research](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/) indicates that new users often have difficulty participating on Stack Overflow and perceive participation barriers on the site and that more experienced users want to ensure that the questions on the site are high quality. Given that, the Staging Ground is ideally a win/win concept which would enable new users to ask better questions, thus increasing the overall quality of questions on the site.

We want to thank the hundreds of people who have participated in the research for the Staging Ground. We truly appreciate your time and feedback. If you’re interested in participating, [opt-in to research participation in your email settings](https://stackoverflow.co/company/research) so that we can contact you for future research studies.

### What we have done

We conducted a five-phase research program to assess a diverse group of users’ thoughts about the Staging Ground concept and to determine how to build the MVP. We obtained feedback from three Stack Overflow user groups (Anonymous users, Newly Registered/Low-Rep users, and Reviewers) from geographically diverse areas to capture a wide array of experiences.

- **Anonymous users**: Users who have not registered on Stack Overflow.
- **Newly Registered/Low-Rep users**: Users with under 200 rep who have registered within the past 12 months and have been seen on the site within the past three months.
- **Reviewers**: Users who have 500+ rep and who have (in the last year) been active with reviewing, close/reopen flagging, or editing.

#### Phase One: Exploring Whether the Staging Ground Holds Value for Different Users

In the first phase of research, we wanted to find out whether our idea of the Staging Ground held value for a diverse set of users. We conducted three surveys completed by a total of 918 users, including Anonymous users, Newly Registered/Low-Rep users, and Reviewers. We learned that this concept has significant potential and that there is strong interest. We also learned about the opportunities and hesitations that users had about the Staging Ground and we used these learnings to iterate on these concepts.

**Key Findings:**

- The survey findings indicated that a large portion of all groups thought that the Staging Ground idea was extremely valuable or very valuable.
- 60% of Low-Rep/Newly Registered Users thought this new feature would be extremely valuable or very valuable, and 50% percent indicated that they would be more likely to ask questions if we implemented the Staging Ground.
- 42% of Reviewers thought this new feature would be extremely useful or very useful.
- 56% of Anonymous Users felt that this new feature would be extremely useful or very useful, and 57% stated that they would be more likely to ask a question for the first time.
- All three user groups were interested in the feature, especially Newly Registered/Low-Rep users. Reviewers thought this new feature would be helpful yet expressed concerns about how they would be rewarded for helping new users, and they also expressed concerns that they may not have enough time to review questions. As we develop the Staging Ground, we will think about ways to streamline the review process (e.g., UI, topic filtering), and we will seek out feedback to determine what form of incentives we will provide to Reviewers.

#### Phase Two: Digging Deeper into User Feedback

In the second phase, we dug deeper into the research findings from the three surveys conducted in the previous phase. We conducted one-on-one interviews with Low-Rep/Newly Registered Stack Overflow users and Reviewers. These insights further revealed what we could improve and gave us additional valuable user perceptions of our core concepts.

**Key Findings:**

- All Newly Registered/Low-Rep and Reviewers interviewed found significant value in the feature and expressed interest in using it. Along with the previous findings, we validated that the Staging Ground is seen as valuable by a diverse group of users and that we should develop this concept.
- Among Reviewers, we learned that the benefits they saw in the Staging Ground included allowing beginners to make mistakes in a safe learning environment, decreased fear of Stack Overflow amongst new users, and maintaining high-quality questions on the site. They were concerned that some Reviewers would not provide friendly feedback, and concerned about the time between asking a question and it going public on the site.
- Among Low-Rep/Newly Registered users, we learned that the benefits they saw in this new feature included increased comfort in asking their first question, higher quality questions and answers on the site, and receiving help from an experienced user. The concern about a time delay was also present with this group.

#### Phase Three: Internal Ideation Stakeholder Workshop

We conducted a workshop internally with various departments across the company. We discussed the existing findings and brainstormed ideas of what this could look like. Our aligned mission statement was: “How might we create a space where new users can more successfully ask a question, thus lowering barriers to participation and increasing question quality on the site?” We came away from this workshop with a variety of strong ideas about what we should include (and not include) in the Staging Ground, and we were able to diverge and then converge on ideas for the overall product direction.

**Key Takeaways:**

- The Staging Ground should be a learning space where users can write good questions and improve their question writing skills.
- We should provide significant guidance and support to new question askers—info on how to write high-quality questions, step-by-step guidance, and how to use the Help Center.
- We should reward Reviewers with badges and potentially other incentives. We should think about how to streamline the question-reviewing process and make it more efficient.

#### Phase Four: MVP Concept Co-Creation Sessions with Users

We conducted interactive one-on-one co-creation interviews to better understand how to design the MVP. Together with a virtual whiteboarding tool, we envisioned what the design and functionality could look like. We learned about the mental models users have about the Staging Ground, and we heavily leveraged these insights to create the MVP designs.

**Key Findings:**

- All of the Newly Registered/Low-Rep users and most of the Reviewers we spoke with expressed strong interest and felt that it would be a valuable addition to the site.
- Among Reviewers, we learned that their perceived benefits of this feature included helping new users ask better questions and building a stronger community. Their concerns about this feature included avoiding the urge to answer a question and that users have to go through another step and wait to receive an answer to their question.
- Newly Registered/Low-Rep users saw the benefit of educating new users on asking good questions, less insecurity about participating, and providing users with a place to learn. The concern about the time delay with questions was present as well.

#### Phase Five: Refining the MVP Designs

We conducted one-on-one MVP design assessment interviews with Low-Rep/Newly Registered users and Reviewers. We discussed the concepts in the previous sessions and the feedback on our MVP designs to understand what users thought. We gained valuable insights about our direction and used these insights to improve our designs.

**Key Findings:**

- Both Reviewers and Newly Registered/Low-Rep users found the Staging Ground to be highly valuable and had positive reactions to the MVP designs.
- Both Newly Registered/Low-Rep users and Reviewers were interested in participating and appreciated the step-by-step nature of the MVP, as well as the support provided (e.g., tips and links to the Help Center). They also liked that it felt like a “safer” psychological space to receive feedback.
- Some users indicated that the feature should feel a little different from Stack Overflow and feel more celebratory and inviting.
- The process of working through each step should be more precise. For example, some users had difficulty figuring out how to edit a question in the Staging Ground; this confusion could be reduced by making the edit button more visible and providing more workflow guidance.

---

**We want to hear your thoughts about these two open research questions:**

- We’ll most likely reward Reviewers who participate with a unique badge for being among the first to participate in the Staging Ground. Once it moves out of the MVP phase, we’re considering an evergreen incentive where Reviewers will be rewarded with milestone badges. What do you think about this?
- During the test period of the Staging Ground, new users who are opted in will not be able to remove themselves from the test. Reviewers who are included in the experiment will be able to opt-out. The plans right now are that if/when it goes live, that all eligible reviewers will have access to the Staging Ground, with the option to opt-out/hide it if they so choose like any other earned privilege. New question askers will remain in the Staging Ground till we determine the qualifications of them being allowed to exit/opt-out.
  For example, should it become default opt-out after users have asked a certain number of questions in the Staging Ground?

## Update

I wanted to clarify a few things that are generating discussion. We are aware of the issues being brought up. We have discussed them internally. Right now, we are working towards a test of the Staging Ground to see how well it could resolve some of the issues on the site regarding low-quality questions.

We know that this and the prior post don't offer many details. That is intentional, as we wanted to establish why we are doing this experiment before showing the nuts and bolts of how it will work. The next few posts we have will go over that in more detail and be an excellent place to provide feedback and critique on what we have so far.

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly...you've already *built* or have already committed to build [what you set out to ask us for feedback on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416428/1079354)??

Comment: @Makoto In the process of building it, development just started.

Comment: So then...it's been committed to.  Going to say this out loud - this *really* takes the wind out of the sails on me wanting to give feedback if you're just going to go forward with something anyway.

Comment: @Makoto Not clear on what you are referring to. We are soliciting input for the two questions we have asked for feedback on because those are not resolved. If you are referring to the staging ground as a whole, then you are correct as we are not soliciting input on whether we should proceed or not with the MVP test.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Reviewers will be able to opt-out". Currently, reviewing is something that people actively partake in – what I would call opt-in – so how does opt-out for reviewers look like? Is that only for the MVP phase, so that participants give up their "spot" for other volunteers, or would this also be relevant "when the Staging Ground should become default opt-out"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi For the test only, we have a test group in the staging ground as a reviewer. They will have the opportunity to opt-out. Assuming we move past the test, we will make a final decision on the opt-in/out status of reviewers.

Comment: "*Last week, we posted here on Meta about the new feature that we are launching, called the Staging Ground*" For anyone else confused that this is the first they're hearing of this, I've edited the title of the referenced Meta post to make it clear it's a new feature announcement, not just an inquiry about random users' first-time question-asking experiences.

Comment: @SpencerG Has the team working on this reviewed/reflected on the previous 'mentorship' program from a few years ago to see what worked well there and what didn't? This process sounds _very_ similar to that program.

Comment: So what happens when we hit 10K questions in the Staging Ground? We still have huge amounts of totally unsalvageable questions asked on daily basis. Non English questions, general computing, networking, asking for libraries and tutorials. You need to be clearer about the rules before people ask questions if you hope this Staging Ground is ever going to work out.

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar: Filtering out such questions *very early* on could be part of the process. Though I didn't see anything about it in this post (I read it all)—I could have overlooked it.

Comment: Taking this opportunity to mention there is an [Official Meta Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room) where we welcome rapid-fire discussion about this meta post or this new feature in general -- in case folks want to discuss it without adhering to the comment or Q&A structure.

Comment: "We’ll most likely reward Reviewers who participate with a unique badge for being among the first to participate in the Staging Ground. Once it moves out of the MVP phase, we’re considering an evergreen incentive where Reviewers will be rewarded with milestone badges." - [So it is a queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp#comment898351_416428). Possibly a glorified one, but it is a queue, and inevitably, it's going to focus the tidal wave of SO's question volume at our extremely short reviewer supply

Comment: Half the point behind my block of comments last week was that we've historically struggled to keep up with volume, but the only reason we've gotten away with it is pushing it under the carpet and dealing with it later. Queues of any kind prevent that, because the queues fill up, and keep filling up, until it's either reviewed or retracted (I can't see any way aging away would be implemented here). The idea can be as fantastic as you want it to be, but if the current volume gets focused in its direction while we're short on reviewers, _it will fail_.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It all depends on who will do the filtering and how. Anything that involves other people will not scale. Regardless of the process and how it is called.

Comment: You can do all the research you want, and all the attempts at making it good, but if you don't have the people on the other side, or don't have enough people on the other side, it's going to crash and burn regardless of what the research says

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine, I am unsure how you define a queue, so I won't tell you that you are wrong. However, I will reiterate it's not a queue in the way that things on the site that are referred to as queues are, at least in the look. The good news is that we are not far away from sharing information on workflow and its appearance. Those posts will be a great place to discuss the labeling of the Staging Ground.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, it was considered. I don't want to give away the other posts covering how the Staging Ground will work, so for now, I am just going to punt on truly answering this question.

Comment: @SpencerG OK, thanks for responding. I have to admit the order of operations here is a little confusing. Wouldn't it make more sense to layout your vision and plans first, and then ask for feedback on each part? It's hard for us to provide feedback if you only tell us about one part at a time.

Comment: @TylerH That is a valuable critique, and I appreciate the feedback. We recently changed internally on how we communicate new features/products to the community. We have missed in the past with under-communicating on these things. The layout here is designed to give increased awareness and more opportunities for feedback, so the community is more partner to the process. This one is slightly out of sorts as the research part on our end started earlier than our new internal process.

Comment: The "Key Findings" under Phase Two and Phase Four are virtually identical. Was this intentional? I expected something more concrete in terms of product design under Phase Four, and not just reiteration of the contributor sentiments that had been previously established. I suspect this might be an editing error, with (an earlier draft of?) the key findings from Phase Two accidentally being placed in Phase Four. Can you confirm?

Comment: @TylerH: I'm tripping over the same thing here. I understand and appreciate the willingness to communicate findings to the community early. But that's not what's happening here. This is more like retroactively communicating findings after the train has left the station. There _has_ been a design phase, but most of what we're hearing about is reactions _to_ the designs without any real details _about_ the designs; this is really confusing. I am excited to learn more about this feature, but these posts are _really_ light on details—despite those details having already been thought through.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine "I can't see any way aging away would be implemented here" For example with an attic. After five days every new question on the staging ground is silently transferred to the staging ground attic, a borderless space that holds everything that nobody else wants to work on.

Comment: @Trilarion can we not just call it outer space? An attic is not geeky enough.

Comment: @Gimby Great. Every new user could start at Uranus. If the question is clear, he can advance to Saturn, if it is focused then forward to Jupiter stage, if it isn't a duplicate (critical point) advance to Mars and finally to the Moon where all "thank you"s are removed and the landing process is started. If the question is abandoned by anyone in the mean time, it derails into "Outer Space". To be more efficient, reviewers could specialize, for example "team Jupiter" would only check if questions are clearly understandable, "team Mars" would only lookout  for duplicates...

Comment: I think the downvotes on this questions aren't really helpful. It's written quite clear and explains a lot. Sure there seems to be disagreement but it's not clear with what exactly. Should everything stay as it is? Should something else be done instead? Or should participation maybe be voluntary instead of mandatory for new users? Or is it a mere "this won't change anything either"? The answers do more to elucidate what might be right and wrong with the idea. I for once, think they are really going in the right direction, influx of bad quality questions is the single biggest problem for SO.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar "Anything that involves other people will not scale." Please hold the line. Based on your current position in the staging queue your question will be ready to be reviewed in 2026, January, 5th, 2pm. Don't call us, we'll call you. Or maybe you just said that SO simply doesn't scale because well there is always only people involved. Maybe the solution is that new question askers have to review themselves and learn from each other somehow.

Comment: @Trilarion "Sure there seems to be disagreement but it's not clear with what exactly." That's why a similar question would likely be unwelcome both on main and meta. By conflating separate announcement, results and questions, any kind of feedback – votes, comments, answers, ... – is hard to disentangle for what exactly it – and its absence - covers or not. There is probably some irony somewhere.

Comment: @Trilarion Point is that too many questions should have not been asked in the first place. But the rules are not clearly presented to new users and as a result we are drowning in such questions. In order to be able to handle anything in more constructive manner we need to have less questions asked or way more reviewers. so any idea that attempts to solve any quality problem without tackling original issue first will fail for the same reasons we are in this mess: lack of reviewers.

Comment: I'm curious as to the make up of these two classes of users you studied. It seems that "New Users" was defined as <200 rep and are relatively active, and "Reviewers" are defined as >500 rep and active in curation. How many of these "Reviewers" are >3000 rep (able to vote to close)? >10k (able to vote to delete)? Have been on the site >1yr? >5yr? Seems to me like those who have been on the site longest have certain notions about what the site should be (i.e., a knowledge base) that may be different from those who have been here a shorter time (e.g., a help desk, a learning site).

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, still I like this idea because it inverts the initial state of questions from open until closed to closed until open. I don't know how to better convince new askers from following the rules and only asking good questions, but I think that this inversion has a higher chance of doing that than keeping everything the old ways.

Comment: @SpencerG I didn't fully understand the opt-out. Are you planning to let people opt-out at any time or just after the initial couple of questions that are well received? In other words, is the staging ground mandatory for at least a certain amount of time or questions or is it completely optional. It didn't become clear to me from the description here.

Comment: You can't really claim that the first post you link was introducing staging ground, you state "its the first in a series of posts" and then go on to bolden a light hearted question about what peoples first posts were like, I'd assumed the feedback you were asking about was going to be part of the rest of the series of posts.

Comment: @Trilarion For new question askers that is what is up for debate. When do we let them out? It's currently undecided but I am in favor of it being mandatory for a certain amount of questions. I have clarified the language a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: @SpencerG If its mandatory, and there ends up not being enough reviewers to keep the questions flowing through, does that not leave a potentially very unwelcoming experience of having to wait an unclear arbitrary amount of time (potentially multiple weeks looking at the close queue) for a reviewer to even consider the question?

Comment: @HereticMonkey "Seems to me like those who have been on the site longest have certain notions about what the site should be (i.e., a knowledge base)" Or rather: a site for enthusiast and professional programmers. That is, a site where a programmer asks a programmer. Not a site where laymen prompts programmers to be their interactive beginner tutorial, so that they don't have to make any study effort themselves. The decay from the former to the latter never had any community support afaik, it is just something the company has been pushing for over time.

Comment: I cannot help but read this whole thing as *"New users would like to have more ways to get their low-quality questions into the system, news at 10"*.

Comment: @TylerH maybe I didn't pay enough attention, but wow, I was completely convinced that previous post was *"just an inquiry about random users' first-time question-asking experiences"*. Thanks for making it clearer.

Comment: *Past user research indicates that new users often have difficulty participating on Stack Overflow and perceive participation barriers on the site* → not only new users. There are communities so hermetic to basic-mid questions that even 12+ years old users get downvoted, and questions closed without any comments. There should be some training on inclusivity for the mods of these comunities.

Answer (score 100):

### Duplicates

I read the entire thing and I do not see where and how you have tackled duplicates.

Stack Overflow is over a decade old. A lot of questions a new user would ask have already been asked and answered. Multiple times. In some cases hundreds of times. What happens when they are asked *yet another* time?

---

### Useless questions

What I found peculiar as well is that the tone of the message is that people *will* be asking questions and you want more questions and more people to participate in getting them into shape. Yet some questions are terrible. Maybe even unsalvageable.

Many times users come in and just dump their entire code for their project and vaguely indicate that it does not work right. No indication *what* does not work, *how* that behaviour is induced, or *where* the problem lies in the literal hundreds of lines of code.

It seems like the expectation here is that reviewers are expected to do debugging (or at least guide the debugging) of such code until there is a suitably small code to ask a question about. Yet by that time the real issue is very likely to emerge. A misplaced conditional, or typo in an argument or similar. What should happen? Post the trivial question on SO? It does not seem right. Whatever the case, the reviewer has just wasted a massive amount of time to get a useless question out of it.

The debugging ones are not the only examples - there are many others that end up with OP getting something, reviewers *and the site* getting nothing. Or nobody getting anything.

I suppose you could argue that this is one less question on SO, but to my mind it does not justify the massive time waste on whoever undertakes trying to fix their questions. It may take 30 minutes to an hour to get the OP to share enough information to even have a question that makes sense. That is 30-60 minutes that should have been spent upfront by OP. That is also 30-60 minutes curators could use to do *anything* else.

---

### Free helpdesk

I cannot help but feel that *many* new users come in with the expectation that we are here to solve their personalised problems. As such, I feel that many of the users who expressed interest in the staging area expect reviewers are there with this goal.

The point of asking a question is to provide lasting value and help future visitors to the site. Coming in with the expectation that SO is there to only serve the question asker leads to bad questions and very much decreased user experience for everybody involved - it frustrates new users and it frustrates curators.

---

I am not sure how this project is judged to be a win/win given that to me it seems like a rather large investment of time with very little return on the part of reviewers. But it would probably be OK for question askers - they would most likely get some form of help with their query even if that does not lead to a useful contribution to the knowledge base.

Comment: "*It seems like the expectation here is that reviewers are expected to do debugging*"  This raises a good point. I had assumed reviewers would be able to "pre-emptively" close such questions (or prevent a question from being posted, basically) if they turn out to be something like a typo, but it's a good idea to get that part of the process explicitly described because I agree it would be quite bad if we had to spend time solving/cleaning up typo questions just to find out they got posted to the site anyway.

Comment: Yea... i could similarly see chameleon questions being a problem here. and XY questions. Are reviewers supposed to just state that it is one, and not help them fix it since doing so would inevitably just solve the problem rather than creating a useful Q/A pair? would the problem being solved without a resulting Q/A pair even be considered a problem?

Comment: You conclude this might be okay for contributors but a loss for reviewers. Yet, your point about "Free helpdesk" makes a compelling argument that this very well could be a lose/lose. E.g., the reviewer is spending time providing meta-feedback on how to improve the question, while the contributor is getting frustrated because they want feedback on their _specific_ problem; in the end, they're both talking past each other, and neither is succeeding in their objective. I've been excited to learn more about the Staging Ground concept, but that framing has me questioning the alignment of interests.

Comment: Exactly; it misses the point entirely. This is a terrible idea. Evidently, there were not enough people involved in the conception who are actually familiar with how Stack Overflow works and what its purpose is.

Comment: We need to find a way to crowd-source the solution. Personally I have a tab open to `questions/tagged/<>?tab=Active` which I sometimes browse looking for something interesting to read or answer. When I see a low value question, my current options are downvote, flag or comment. Give me a quick way to provide better constructive feedback and I'll use it on my random sample of questions, but I'm not going to review some FIFO queue. Let people choose to show / hide low value questions in the way they are comfortable with.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman You have [close-vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Applying a close vote is a great way to leave feedback. The system will do it automatically, on your behalf, when the question gets closed. I assume you are familiar with this feature and are using it when you come across questions that don't meet our expectations or are otherwise unsuitable for the site? Also, don't underestimate the impact and importance of downvoting—it is an *essential* quality-control mechanism, and has a lot more effectiveness than most users realize.

Comment: "with very little return on the part of reviewers" Makes me in general think about what the return for reviewers is here? I thought reviewing is more seen like a necessary chore than a very positive way of spending time.

Comment: @Trilarion "reviewers" here uses the terminology used in the question - it's people who visit the staging area in order to provide feedback, guidance and in generalpolish questions posted there. The question opposes them to Newly Registered/Low-Rep users who would be the ones posting the questions in the staging area and receiving the guidance from the reviewers. Yes, the term is ambiguous because we already have it for "people who take on tasks in review queues", however I didn't want to make up yet another term here but echo the terminology from the question.

Comment: @CodyGray _"Evidently, there were not enough people involved in the conception who are actually familiar with how Stack Overflow works and what its purpose is."_ That sentence is starting to sound too familiar.

Comment: @CodyGray "This is a terrible idea." I'm not so pessimistic. I mostly see it as not much of a change except for questions being auto-closed at the beginning and needing reopening before being able to answered compared to the opposite before. Nothing else changes. If we are a helpdesk then we are it already now. Already now a review frequently ends up with a closed question, so no real win for the site. Nothing changes there. As I read it, it mostly means that we can tell users what to do before they can get answers, do the incentive to follow that is actually higher.

Answer (score 85):

**TL;DR:** please focus on what we have first, instead of piling more on top of it.  We've been struggling [for years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285438/6296561), and while improvements have been made, we still have a long way to go before the situation resembles anything close to being overall under control.

> 60% of Low-Rep/Newly Registered Users thought this new feature would be extremely valuable or very valuable, and 50% percent indicated that they would be more likely to ask questions if we implemented the Staging Ground

I like stats. Here's some more:

[93% of all users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1095929/user-reputation-by-percentage) are currently <100 rep, and that assumes 100 is the threshold for being low-rep. This also blatantly disregards who asks; a lot of accounts are abandoned for a number of reasons.

Here's [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1568845/user-questions-by-current-reputation-for-3-months) for questions over the past three months. It's severely flawed, fails to account for votes gained over time, and only considers the users in their current state. It also doesn't deal well with deletion. Consequently, this data is going to get worse as time progresses, and that query will also change as time progresses. Yet, look at the numbers today (limited to 800 rep because copying from SEDE is annoying):

| Count | Percentage | Rep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 239254 | 65.6 | 1-99 |
| 30347 | 8.32 | 100-199 |
| 6097 | 1.67 | 200-299 |
| 12851 | 3.53 | 300-399 |
| 8432 | 2.31 | 400-499 |
| 6178 | 1.69 | 500-599 |
| 4740 | 1.30 | 600-699 |
| 4074 | 1.12 | 700-799 |

A whopping 65.6% of all 365920 asked in this period are by users who currently have <100 rep. If we consider everyone under 200 rep low-rep users through a bunch of secondary currently hypothetical processes, that's 73.95% of all questions overall in this period. At 60% interest, assuming your research is solid and obviously assuming it's implemented in a way that maintains a 60% usage rate, that's 161760 over 2.5 months, or 2215 posts per day that get reviewed through this staging area.

Because these shift over time, the base numbers from the SEDE query represent a lower boundary. That lower boundary is, as is about to be demonstrated, extremely high.

Due to the complex and time-consuming nature of the reviews, we can't even compare it to a current queue. Let's consider [First Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/stats), a queue that perfectly demonstrates why queues overall need more focus, but don't get any. It's sitting at 5k questions at 1393 reviews so far today. A single review is required to complete the questions, but because these forms of queues are easier to automate the interface of, it's fairly trivial to get through a lot, fast. That's shy of 1000 reviews too few to keep up with the staging ground, a system that fundamentally relies on quick responses. This doesn't even account for weekend reviewer deficit, or how asking rates tend to be higher on weekdays.

That doesn't translate to a staging ground, unless you're grinding badges, another concern I'll get back to whenever the review ban system, or lack thereof, is detailed. The reviews here require a lot more time, at least if the intent is to actively guide users, and it doesn't end up being a half-way, shortcut-ridden implementation that essentially becomes First Questions but with a broader scope for what gets entered, at which point this will all have been useless anyway, so let's disregard that for now.

Even if we assume a best-case scenario, after the initial hype for reviewing dies down, and assuming the threshold is identical to first questions (at 500 rep), we'd still be at least 1000 reviews short daily. You've been extremely vague on the details, however, so what if it's locked until 2k? Then we have [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats). Granted, it requires at least twice as many reviews as First Questions to complete a task, but the only reason it isn't overflowing is because of the 500 question limit. Even then, at 557 reviews, that's over 1.5k fewer reviews than we need, and again, not accounting for weekdays seeing higher volumes than weekends, a number I don't want to calculate because reasons.

And this doesn't even account for this sentence:

> but we’re curious to hear your thoughts about when the Staging Ground should become default opt-out.

Which bumps the 2.3k figure, unmodified for weekday/weekend volume differences, up to a full **3289 questions**, a full 1000 questions more. This little bump alone is enough to almost fully counter the entire reviewer force on First Questions. Even assuming the suggested edits reviewers are able to fully keep up at no efficiency loss, which is completely unrealistic, that's as much as 5.8 times fewer reviews per day than needed.  And I'm *still* not done. With 50% being more likely to ask questions, that number is going even higher. However, "more likely to ask questions" is an awful and unquantifiable metric that I can't use to even begin to guesstimate the possible question increase. It's certain it'll be higher, but the question I can't answer is by how much.

And finally, this doesn't account for the possibility that higher-rep users are also allowed to submit questions to the staging ground, which could further inflate the number.

**TL;DR** too many questions, too few reviewers

Unless some substantial, and I do mean *substantial* improvements are made, the queue will eventually back up into oblivion, and require a burn that, while successful, [doesn't last](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251493/6296561) because reviewers burn out, or just get tired, and stop. Worst-case scenario, [2019 repeats itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385023/6296561) and all queues explode. No one wins here.

You've already acknowledged there's a workflow, so people do have to get involved. This means it's a queue, even if it's not similar to what we currently have for reviews, and people have to review it.

Based on there being badges, there's clearly a concept of completion, further reinforcing the concept that it is a queue. However, unlike most queues we currently have, the volume this queue is going to face is so much higher than all the other queues, possibly combined, and we already lack reviewers to get on with our current day-to-day gruntwork here on the ground; I'm once again asking you to PLEASE try to stabilize the baseline before throwing even more work at already overworked volunteers.

Comment: Godspeed, Zoe.  My confidence in the company actually recognizing this feedback and taking action on it is nonexistent, so I can only salute you for this.

Comment: Does anyone remember the Mentorship project? It's the same thing all over again. Arguably, mentorship did improve the quality of posts and user experiences (although not really enough to justify the time investment, in my opinion), yet it just didn't scale. We don't have enough volunteers to both improve questions *and* answer them. The focus should not be on a "staging ground", but rather on a way to **block more questions outright from submission, before any humans ever see them.** Another option might be improving and broadening the [tour]. Theme: no continued human involvement.

Comment: This also indirectly gets into the concern that "some Reviewers would not provide friendly feedback". This happens when there isn't an incentive to slow down and spend time providing specific feedback on individual posts. That's counterproductive when there's a huge queue: quantity trumps quality. And that incentive is exasperated by the fact that most contributors don't respond to feedback—and those who do often respond poorly. That encourages reliance on canned and/or curt comments that aren't specific to the post. Neither seem useful for new contributors, and are rarely taken as "friendly".

Comment: So, give users 100 CVs per day? :-) 'm down for that.

Comment: "TL;DR too many questions, too few reviewers" - devil's advocate: this might be a good thing because it could mean many of the garbage questions being asked every day are left to rot in the staging ground instead of being posted on the main site. This could very well lead to an improvement in question quality, just not in the way envisioned by SO. Although this would probably only be a temporary effect as the help vampires would soon figure out they need to opt out of the staging ground to get any responses...

Comment: @CodyGray "yet it just didn't scale" You could still offer it on a voluntary basis, i.e. have a pool of reviewers willing to spend extra time and then open it to new users who voluntarily want to improve their skills on a first come first served basis. Why was the mentorship project not continued under this condition?

Comment: @l4mpi I was thinking about that too, but this process will stall the small handful of good questions as well, unfortunately.

Comment: @CertainPerformance people who ask decent questions are probably able to read and have a minimum level of awareness, and thus would have a way higher chance to find and click the "opt out" box than the brainless zombies who spam SO with misformatted questions that indicate they didn't even look at the post preview...

Comment: "Unless some substantial, and I do mean substantial improvements" The only free labor I see that we would have is the question asker themselves, so for example for every question that you ask you have to do 10 simple reviews (does this question show research, do you understand it, how many questions are asked there, is the code runnable, ...) that are then aggregated in the hope that statistically even new askers know something (or can learn). Sometimes it's easier to see the errors of others than to see your own errors.

Comment: @Trilarion That sounds like a tremendously, exceedingly, extremely (and whatever adverb you can think of) horrible idea. That's a system begging to be gamed and abused if I ever see one.

Comment: @PasserBy It's so cheap being critical of something. But before you tried it you'll never know really. Something has to change with regard to new questions and their quality and I would really be surprised if we get more professional reviewers on board. We'll see what happens. Should this idea ever take off, I want to be credited for it.

Comment: @CodyGray Blocking a large percentage of questions automatically in a reliable way (block only/mainly bad questions, not good ones) sounds like it would be a really difficult problem to solve, even if SO had the best Data Scientists. The much simpler solution (but we can work towards both) would be to change the First Posts queue so questions only go public *after* passing review (and then investing more into figuring out what to send there and improving the quality of reviews). That should dissuade a lot of people from asking bad questions, which should mitigate having too few reviewers.

Comment: @NotThatGuy, That is ideally what that queue should be for, but it would likely block a number of decent on-topic questions that need a quick turnaround. However the mitigating effects of sending a message out to all of the junk (or potentially junk) posters might alleviate that concern to some extent. Hard to know for sure....

Comment: There are few reviewers, because there are no incentives to review. There are no incentives to provide *good* reviews either. Recently, I helped a user find a solution to <https://stackoverflow.com/q/71549470/3840170>, in the comments, because the question was immediately closed as ostensibly unclear, even if it made perfect sense to me, and presumably anyone else familiar with the subject matter. I was also accompanied by two people, neither of whom understood the problem, but rushed to ‘solve’ it anyway. So I am not even sure if having more reviewers would help anything at all.

Answer (score 25):

> We’ll most likely reward Reviewers who participate with a unique badge for being among the first to participate in the Staging Ground. Once it moves out of the MVP phase, we’re considering an evergreen incentive where Reviewers will be rewarded with milestone badges. What do you think about this?

Special one-time badges are a bad idea. Compared to badges someone can earn in an evergreen way, one-time badges just say "I was here first" and lead to elitism/us-vs-them. There's no reason to give Reviewers *now* a badge that you don't think a Reviewer *next year* should be able to earn, when they are doing the same work. If this were a video game whose ongoing survival depended on a dedicated community the first year or so in order to survive, that kind of thing makes sense.

> We’re planning on having the Staging Ground be default opt-in (newly registered users included in the test will not be able to opt-out, however, Reviewers will be able to opt-out) for the MVP phase, but we’re curious to hear your thoughts about when the Staging Ground should become default opt-out. For example, should it become default opt-out after users have asked a certain number of questions in the Staging Ground?

- In general, forcing participation for new askers is probably a good thing, but **any** user should be able to opt-in to the asking feature, if they want to. I think we would benefit from clarification regarding the two groups: askers and reviewers. Opting in as a reviewer should be considered separately but it's not clear which group you're talking about at each point when you talk about opting in or out in the announcement.
- Re: "become default opt-out", do you mean *automatically* opt askers out after a certain number of questions? If not, I don't know what it means.
- I also think the criteria for when to opt-in askers should consider not just "number of questions asked" but also "time since last question asked". If someone hasn't asked a question in 5 years, there's a good chance they're going to be rusty at it. Age of the user account might be good to take into account, but at a lesser weight (e.g. require a user to go through the process to ask a question for at least the first question they ask if it's been > 1 year since their last question, but if a user has been around `n` years or asked `y` questions already, only force the process for one question. For new users, force the process for three, or whatever).

Comment: For clarification, the only askers who will start out in the SG are new askers to the site. We have discussed should a post MVP release happen that existing users can use it as well. I updated the main text to reflect this.

Answer (score 20):

To be clear, you’ve:

- Asked new users if they’d like someone to proof read their post for free (of course they would)
- Defined higher rep users of at least 500 reputation and asked these if new users could do with someone proof reading their first question (sure, new posts regularly lack quality)
- Asked your own staff if this proof reading idea would work (good in principle i guess?)

But I can’t see where you say you’ve asked those that have been around for x years and understand how the site works if this is a good idea?

Do you not see the issue with that?

Nothing burns me out quicker than the wave of users that do not understand they aren’t asking a question for themselves, but essentially writing a wiki post in the form of a q+a for the *next* person to find an answer.  In fact, I’ve seen [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71445169/1324033) from a user in this user group this *year* that I would say have understood this.

The fact that this rarely happens is proof that StackOverflow is meeting its goal of making this a resource as **most questions from new users have already been answered**. But for some unknown reason, (cough money cough) SOCorp doesn’t seem to recognise this goal anymore and consistently keep ramming this narrative down our throats that we should be here to answer all questions regardless of their previous existences.

So given you’ve decided you’re definitely going to push forward with this staging ground you need to realise you’ll need more proof readers to take part than just the few remaining reviewers so here’s two groups you should be asking.

1. Those that have been active for x years (I suggest 4-5 maybe minimum)
2. Your own staff since you were encouraged during the Monica saga to become active in the community.

Oh and as a spoiler, I doubt group one would be too eager to jump aboard given how much we already deal with this on a daily basis without needing to make it a focus group.

Comment: To be fair, proofreading first users posts is part of the curation activity on SO. Whether it be called staging ground or not, that's what reviewer are actually doing all the time. The concern here would probably be that with a staging ground first time posters would actually take that service for granted even more than now instead of paying more attention to do sufficient research on their own, right? It would probably also depend on the implementation details, which haven't been made public yet. Maybe insufficient research could be treated better within one suitable kind of staging ground.

Comment: @Trilarion - The concern I see is they haven't really defined the expected output of this staging ground is as far as I can tell, I assume it was a holding pen to prepare a question ready for it to be published to production (main site), which the post then is treated as it is now after been appropriately massaged. But thats on a failed assumption that the vast proportion should need to be asked at all.

Comment: If we can tell people, look no research done, not a good question, before they can get an answer, they might even be inclined to add actual research and maybe find an answer themself. But on the other hand everything would be much better, if only people had more realistic expectations and everything you said. But if this was the case, a staging ground could actually be a good idea, I think.

Comment: @Trilarion - I wish that would be the case but if you ever ask "what research have you done" in a comment you either get flat out ignored or often a variation "I didn't know what to research". Of course some are responsive to this and do end up going on to further defining their question which is nice... As I've put above, the  staging ground sounds good in principle but I can't see how it could possibly succeed in its execution

Comment: @Trilarion That is precisely the intention. Reviewers are not intended to answer questions but to point out where it needs improvement. Something we have toyed around with is adding canned responses for the most common reasons why they wouldn't be ready for Stack Overflow so that it's not a ton of effort on the reviewer's part.

Comment: @SpencerG I can see myself pointing out to first time askers all that is wrong with their questions, but I would really hope that at some point they have learned on their own how to ask a good question. So if somebody doesn't ask a good question on the third or fourth try, I might just give up. Also the point of Sayse here is that many of the current new questions should not be asked at all. For this, teaching people how to search more efficiently is actually much more useful. I don't want to repeat the very same things over and over again. Have you tried to turn it off and on again..

Comment: "Nothing burns me out quicker than the wave of users that do not understand they aren’t asking a question for themselves, but essentially writing a wiki post in the form of a q+a for the next person to find an answer." I mean... Yes and no. This is the only thing I take any issue with in your post. No first time user will get that.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I agree and mention that in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416652/new-user-experience-deep-dive-into-our-research-on-the-staging-ground-how-do/416721?noredirect=1#comment900749_416756) on a different answer here, its down to SOCorp as to whether or not they want to continue with this goal or become quora2

Answer (score 16):

#### How do you feel about review badges and opt-in settings?

¯\_(ツ)_/¯?

Default opt-in (aka you'll have to opt-out of it if you don't want it if I'm understanding correctly) will certainly ensure participation by the majority of new users (particularly those most likely to ignore asking guidance), but it'd also mean people who aren't interested in such guidance may accidentally find their way into the system as well, creating a frustrating experience for both them and the reviewers.

Review badges... meh? I'm sure some badge hunters might care, but ultimately the incentive to participating here is/should be curation/helping users. I'd avoid making earning a badge or some privilege unrelated to this tool the primary incentive.

I'd be entirely against a limited-time badge to promote people participating, as that will simply lead to a rush of people participating to earn a limited-time badge and give useless data as far as whether or not participation will be high enough to support the feature long-term.

Comment: That's not to say I don't think it should reward a badge, more, this shouldn't be marketed to the public as "Hey! Come earn a badge by participating in this new thing!"

Comment: Maybe instead of default opt-in you can just ask if a new user wants guidance making sure he understands the importance of asking good questions before he confirm his choice, of default opt-in until a certain rep and after the mark is surpassed prompt them to disable this feature if they feel like they can ask questions on their own, but maybe I'm putting too much faith in new users

Comment: I do think default opt-in is the way to go to meet the needs of the majority of users... assuming we have more than enough reviewers to handle the workload (rather big assumption.) it's just it'd need a way to make sure we can deal with the problems that will cause

Comment: "*but it'd also mean people who aren't interested in such guidance may accidentally find their way into the system as well, creating a frustrating experience for both them and the reviewers.*" I don't see a downside here. Either they need the guidance, and it's good they got funneled into the system. Or they don't need it, and it'll be a rubber stamp for reviewers to send them on their way.

Answer (score 15):

> How might we create a space where new users can more successfully ask a question, thus lowering barriers to participation and increasing question quality on the site?

Depends on what you mean with successfully asked? Hopefully with question quality in mind. Something like the number of positively received questions minus the number of negatively received questions or similar metric that can be tested.

> We should provide significant guidance and support to new question askers—info on how to write high-quality questions, step-by-step guidance, and how to use the Help Center.

That should have been provided to new question askers all time along. I guess the idea is here that the staging area is better in providing that support than existing feedback mechanisms.

> We should reward Reviewers with badges and potentially other incentives.

I'm so past badges and do not expect a lot there, but it surely doesn't hurt either.

> we heavily leveraged these insights to create the MVP designs. .. We gained valuable insights about our direction and used these insights to improve our designs.

You created and improved designs. But these designs aren't presented here. So, we cannot comment on them, yet.

> making the edit button more visible and providing more workflow guidance.

Making the edit button more visible and providing more workflow guidance might be a good general approach. Maybe consider doing it also outside of the staging ground.

> ..badges. What do you think about this?

As said above, I'm not interested in any more badges. Others might, but with me there is zero interest. I guess, after a few years of participation and the first couple of badges, they simply lose most of their appeal.

> For example, should it become default opt-out after users have asked a certain number of questions in the Staging Ground?

Yes. At some point users should be assumed to know how to participate "normally" on Stack Overflow, i.e. writing good questions by themselves and being able to get answers to these good questions as soon as possible.

I still like the idea of a staging ground very much; it reminds me of the old Stack Overflow Academy idea. However, I think it requires a lot of work from the reviewers side and I'm not sure that work is actually doable. We might be constrained there.

What I like most about the stage ground is that **questions can only be answered after being vetted. That is a real game changer.** It's equivalent to start questions in closed state and having to have them opened first. But on the other hand, the amount of vetting that would need to be done (is it clear, is it focused, is it answerable, has it been answered already, ...) is so immense that it simply might not work out that well in practice. But in principle it's the right direction. Therefore I really, really hope that you will continue with it.

Only on-topic, non-duplicate questions should ever be answered.

Comment: _"questions can only be answered after being vetted"_, due to the optional nature of the staging ground, this does foreshadow a scenario where users opt-out just so they can get the darn question out.

Comment: @PasserBy Potentially, but simply requiring a user to come back and make an active action to get out of the staging ground may eliminate some of the worst unclear abandoned questions. Which can only be a good thing.

Comment: @PasserBy Initially I assumed that one cannot opt out directly at the beginning. Now I'm not sure anymore. If it's completely optional, people will probably quickly bypass it if they aren't satisfied.

Answer (score 9):

I'm a fairly new user myself (I just recently started using SO on a daily basis).

Before starting to post questions, I used the site a lot to get answers like anyone else when facing problems, and got an idea on how a good question is structured and presented without even reading the official guidelines.

Eventually, I started asking questions, and I found it pretty easy to post quality questions, even on my first ones. Surely I posted some slightly bad ones, but it happens once in a while if you genuinely think your question is good enough and you put all the research you could have put into it before posting.

This is to say some users might already have enough skill to post a good question even if they are new or asking their first questions, and a default opt-in could not work as intended in some cases:

Let’s say a user has a classic opinion-based question, and they just want to post it because they want help to decide what framework to use for their homework. They clearly can’t post it without opting out, so if the opt-out is easy to achieve, they will do that in a matter of seconds – making the feature just something annoying to skip the first time because they believe they can post good questions without the help of tools and they just want to go straight to asking questions.

On the other side of the spectrum, some users might be already able to ask good questions, and they will be presented with a playground they might believe is the only correct way to post questions, limiting their ability to post a good question the way they really want to.

Maybe instead of default opt-in, you can just ask if a new user wants guidance, but making sure they understand the importance of asking good questions before they confirm their choice.
*Or* default opt-in and after a certain reputation threshold is surpassed, prompt them to disable this feature if they feel like they can ask questions on their own.

But maybe I’m putting too much faith in new users.

Comment: The post does not provide much detail about what the review process looks like - it is stated that it has a "step-by-step" nature but not much else. However, I can imagine that in the situation that you describe, where a new user already knows how to ask a high-quality question, the review process can be fairly quick, allowing the reviewer to just approve of the different steps without the need for intervention or guidance. Even if the question doesn't fit the template or all the steps perfectly then the reviewer can still recognize that the question is good and approve it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As a new user (who didn't participate in the survey) who started coding in November and regularly visits SO, I can say that it is a bit daunting to ask/ answer on the site. Yet participating is of very high value to me as a learner.

I once asked on another platform why people are asking their questions there instead of on SO, considering that the questions are so much easier to understand and respond to there. One response was something like "NO WAY there are developers on there," which reflects a fear of being castigated.

While I can understand why a person who has been contributing to the site for 10+ years is tired of seeing bad/ poorly formatted questions, what I don't understand is why they bother with them. Bad, poorly formatted, and low-level questions could be left for people like me, who have some knowledge and are using the Q&A to expand their ability to seek and find solutions to common problems. We are not (yet) exhausted by the repetition. We have some sympathy for the users who may be asking a duplicate question because they don't have the vocabulary to formulate effective search terms. Plus, nothing helps you learn how not to write a bad question like trying to understand someone else's bad question. That seems like a win-win to me.

So what I think would be great - and might address a lot of the angst among the veterans here - would be if question vetting were performed at different levels based on reputation, starting at the bottom.

Comment: The issue is that [so] does a really poor job of demonstrating its original goal. The idea was to make a resource of solutions to every question a developer could have so it says its a Q+A because thats how the resources are structured, but the problem now is that most of those questions have been answered a lot so now the curation is more like wikipedia where multiple locations of the same information would be detrimental to maintain and keep the best information easy to find

Comment: "what I don't understand is why they bother with them" Because it is not our choice – we *get* bothered by them. There is no way to filter out such questions without reading them, so *everything* that involves looking for *any* questions – those to answer, those to use as duplicates, or even those to which we want an answer ourselves – also includes those bad questions. Just letting them be means a) we keep accumulating them and b) we do *not* tell people that they are writing bad questions *and need to improve*.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is a filter that keeps them away from you until they pass through people like me. SO has not yet delineated the mechanism for vetting questions, so I'm suggesting this one. I think it would satisfy a lot of people while serving the mission of the site.

Comment: The issue is that reputation doesn't give any indication of your technical ability, you could have 20 years of experience and new to stackoverflow or you could have mastered your google-fu and gained thousands of reputation without ever writing a line of code

Comment: This kind of "levels" has been suggested before. Without re-iterating everything, the core issue is that splitting the userbase means exactly that: splitting the userbase. So "low-level" users *don't* really learn what "high-level" users expect, because it's a huge Chinese Whispers game with sometimes not even *any* connection. Also, "low-level" based on reputation is not the same as "unexperienced" – we would still force many good contributors to trudge through *even more* chores to reach experts.

Comment: See for example [Would it be a terrible idea to split SO up into a tiered platform?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252781/would-it-be-a-terrible-idea-to-split-so-up-into-a-tiered-platform)

Comment: A person of high ability/ low reputation can change that in a matter of days. And I'm not suggesting a tiered platform, merely a filter. For example, I have 80 reputation and it took a lot of time to get that. This is child's play for an expert. But if there were reputation to be earned by going on and looking at questions from people with <20 reputation (arbitrarily chosen) and helping them get either easy answers or access to more experienced readers, I don't see how that could hurt. It seems like it would be both more welcoming and less annoying, depending on where you sit on the spectrum.

Comment: "We are not (yet) exhausted by the repetition." Believe me, that happens very quickly. Vetting a question isn't a trivial task. There are so many of them, but there are not enough of us (and I just included you and me together, because it doesn't really matter how much rep you have as long as you review accurately). Unfortunately, "Bad, poorly formatted, and low-level questions" cannot be left for you, because you would be overwhelmed by them. I may be wrong, but I'm very confident. If the staging ground fails, then because of a fundamental misunderstanding about the available review capacity.

Comment: Feel free to make a proper proposal for your idea. Comments were meant to provide some background and different perspective, not to shoot you down, but I think we are at the limit of depth of what can be reasonably discussed in comments.

Comment: See also [a comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416652/new-user-experience-deep-dive-into-our-research-on-the-staging-ground-how-do?cb=1#comment900191_416661) "The only free labor I see that we would have is the question asker themselves" and this answer touches upon that too. The advantage would be a larger base of potential reviewers but the disadvantage would be that they all do not know how to review very well. Without some kind of quality control of the quality control that surely wouldn't work. On the other hand it's probably good training looking at others.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "See for example Would it be a terrible idea to split SO up into a tiered platform?" Very nice reading. Basically says that the problems were known at least as far back as 2014, probably even earlier. And we are still discussing possible solutions in 2022. One (or more) of the following must be true: it wasn't such a big problem after all and the system still works more or less, it is a really hard problem that cannot be solved easily, we never really tried to solve it one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

##### What Happens With Questions That Don't Make It?

There needs to be some thought around what happens to questions that get answered during the asking process. As things stand a significant proportion of first questions are answered from the comments as someone picks up a typo or asks whether the asker has tried X or Y. I think we should anticipate a similar proportion of questions will never graduate because they have been solved in staging. Even now I probably solve more problems by formulating my SO question (and then not posting it because I don't need it any more) than I get answers on SO.

Most of these questions are going to lean towards non-reproducible or duplicates anyways, so it's no real loss for the quality of the site  (probably a win, practically) but what does it mean for the user in question? Does that count as their one for the staging area or do they keep being routed through it until they graduate? Is there any rep reward for the reviewers who helped them?

I enjoy helping people figure out how to use the site and this might be one of the main places I engage with SO when it becomes available, but each person we help is likely to be a much bigger time and effort investment than the existing queues. Once people who came through that process reach sufficient rep there might be a good opportunity to push the idea of them paying it forward by helping out in the staging area. Or allow users with a lower rep to help out in the staging area before they can help on the main site. Given a degree of gatekeeping from experienced reviewers on the way out that could help new users gain a little rep in a "safe" environment and understand more about how the wider site works. Whether early stage users are interested in doing that is another question, of course.