# Has SO considered a gentler approach to newb questions?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I saw this (following link), and I thought "my daughter (age 9) would ask something like this, and I want her to get good answers and not a brush-off".

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159683/image-processing-in-r*

I think closing this question is a missed-opportunity with the framework here.  This was asked by someone who is very new.  They *can’t* ask good questions because they don't know the language; they don't know what they don't know.

Having a "newb" tag and "merging" the question with an existing one instead of closing it is an approach that brings more learners into the domain more quickly, which is a good part of the value proposition and main effort of SO.

I don't post in meta much.  I don't follow conversations.

How has SO approached "newbs" in a way that increases engagement and attention?

The aggressive and "do it right or don't do it" would not work well with my daughters. Even though they are bright, and very intelligent, they also do not put up with perceived disrespect (or abuse) from others. How is SO a place with a minimum barrier to entry for them?

Comment: Minimum age is 13 so definitely aren't catering to 9 year olds.

Comment: If someone is so new (to a technology) they can't ask a good question then they're on the wrong community. They need a tutorial or education site, not a Q&A site for **specific** problems.

Comment: "*Having a "newb" tag*" that's not what tags are for.

Comment: "*How has SO approached "newbs" in a way that increases engagement and attention?*" [New User Experience: Deep Dive into our Research on the Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416652) | [Mentorship Research Project - Results + Wrap-Up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357198) | [Upcoming Feature Test: Ask Wizard for New Users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416322) | [The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671) | [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513) just a few from different points of time.

Comment: Stack Overflow has approached this problem from a number of different directions, but it always comes back to "Read the site usage instructions. Follow them."

Comment: see also: [When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366858/839601)

Comment: How is merging the question with an existing one a better experience? If anything from the new question is added to the existing one, it will almost certainly lower the quality if not be outright nonsensical, and if nothing is added to it then how is that meaningfully different from the way duplicate closure works now?

Answer (score 25):

If a question doesn't meet our standards, **it deserves to be closed**.  Expertise does not factor into this.

The question in full is:

> I have started learning image processing on R.I want to change brightness of images to make all the images equally brighten.Can anyone help me by suggesting some way to achieve this.. Can extracting RGB component of the image help me in solving above task?? Thankyou

If I break this down it reads like this:

> I have started to learn X.  I want to do Y.  Can someone help me with this?  Would Z work?

This question doesn't past muster even if it's asked by a veteran in the field with 15 years of experience.

Stack Overflow *can* be a great place to learn, but it's not the case that we're here to *explicitly* teach others.  That's something else entirely that hasn't been built yet, or at least hasn't had compensation built into it at a level that would be satisfactory yet.

To put it more bluntly:

You can absolutely learn how to drive a stick-shift/manual vehicle while driving on a major highway, but it is not the responsibility of the highway administration to teach you which pedal is the clutch and which is the brake.

Comment: Nor is it the responsibility of law-enforcement officers to cut you a break for failure to comply with traffic laws because you're just learning to distinguish the pedals. Our rules apply equally to all questions; the user (or their backstory) is not relevant.

Answer (score 9):

As [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) states, "asking a good question will nearly always require you to know enough to know what you don't know." There's no shame in not being at that point in solving a problem yet (we've all been there at some point); it just means that they're not ready to post a Stack Overflow question yet.

People are [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to do lots of research before posting a question here for that exact reason: you generally can't ask a specific question until you know what you don't know.

Also, the community moderates content, not people. Treating questions from newbies differently for the purpose of moderation violates that principle because we'd be considering who posted the content above what the actual content is.

It also seems fundamentally unfair to allow content that violates site quality standards to stand merely because it's a newbie question when we'd close the exact same question from a higher-rep user.

The unfortunate fact is that, almost by definition, most low-quality content is posted by low-rep users. This sometimes creates the perception that we're being overly hostile to newcomers, even if we're actually treating people basically the same way.